# AmazonEC2Client timeout from FARGATE container in private subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, aws-fargate, aws-sdk-net

I'm attempting to make an `AmazonEC2Client` SDK call from a .NET program running in a FARGATE container in a Private Subnet:

```
using (var vpcClient = new AmazonEC2Client(_awsCredentials, _regionEndpoint))
{
    var listSubnets = await vpcClient.DescribeSubnetsAsync(new DescribeSubnetsRequest()
    {
        Filters = new List<Filter>()
        {
            new Filter()
            {
                Name = "vpc-id",
                Values = new List<string> { _vpcId }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The code works OK from my development laptop, but it stops cold making the request when deployed to AWS.

The network mode on the FARGATE container is:

```
"networkMode": "awsvpc",
```

What am I missing here?  A security group configuration?

I set "All Traffic" for the VPC CIDR in both in Inbound and Outbound rules for the security group used by the FARGATE container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A resource running in a private subnet of your VPC doesn't have access to *anything* outside of the VPC. The AWS API which you are trying to interact with via the AWS SDK exists outside of the VPC.

Your options are to either add a NAT Gateway in a public subnet of the VPC, and configure a route to that NAT Gateway in the private subnet(s). Or, create an AWS Private Link VPC Endpoint in your VPC for the specific AWS service you are trying to interact with.

It looks like you are trying to interact with the VPC service. I think, due to legacy reasons, the VPC service is actually accessed through the AWS EC2 API, so you would need to create a VPC endpoint for the EC2 service.

Comment: I created a VPC Endpoint for the EC2 service (com.amazonaws.{region}.ec2) and configured it for my private subnets and security group used by fargate, but still get the same issue.

Comment: What is the error message? A network timeout or something?

Comment: Yea, TimeoutException on the SDK call from .NET.  It wreaks of a network path issue like you mentioned above.

Comment: That API endpoint is definitely listed under the EC2 API: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeSubnets.html I don't know what else to tell you really. You might want to try debugging that connectivity from an EC2 instance in the same subnet or something.

Comment: Also, do you have DNS Support and DNS Hostnames enabled for your VPC?

Comment: DNS hostnames/resolution = Enabled

Comment: Actually this is working after setting `Enable private DNS names` in the VPC Endpoint. Thanks!

Comment: Ugh. Now having same issue with `AmazonCloudWatchLogsClient` trying to execute `StartLiveTailAsync`.  I have a VPC Endpoint for `com.amazonaws.{region}.logs` but still times out on that call.